# LED flicker vs human perception

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electric-circuits, light-emitting-diodes

I have read this question:

https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43070/why-do-the-headlights-of-supercars-looking-flashing-on-video

where cdunn says:

> So when you slow it down, you're catching things your eye isn't fast enough to catch.

So far so good. So human's can't have a perception of the led flickering, because the LED is turned off for a period of time that is too short for humans to physically perceive.

Now the human perception is around 150 FPS (max, but average of 60), that is what I have found at least.

Now the back up camera is around 30FPS as I have found.

So basically why is the answer saying that the human eye is not fast enough to catch the LED flicker, whereas the camera is. Is it not the opposite way around?

Question:

1. Why is LED flicker only visible through the camera (and not with the naked eye)?

Comment: If there are people out there who notice 150 fps flicker, going to a movie or watching TV must be miserable for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED flicker is not visible with the naked eye because the intensity is to high. The eye is saturated from to much light. Reduce the intensity of the light (driving the LED with less power or shielding the eye with strong tinted glass), and you will see the flicker.

And with the 30 fps camera it is the stroboscope effect.